# How to manage connections and Clients in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I started working with Twisted Framework, I wrote a TCP server and I connect to it throw Telnet, it works fine. Now I want to manage connections and connected clients( sending data, cutting connections, etc etc) using an GUI like PyUI or GTK..

this is my code

```
import sys
import os
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.python import log

    class Server(protocol.Protocol):

        def dataReceived(self, data):
            log.msg ("data received: %s"%data)
            self.transport.write("you sent: %s"%data)

        def connectionMade(self):
            self.client_host = self.transport.getPeer().host
            self.client_port = self.transport.getPeer().port
            if len(self.factory.clients) >= self.factory.clients_max:
                log.msg("Too many connections !!")
                self.transport.write("Too many connections, sorry\n")
                self.transport.loseConnection()
            else:
                self.factory.clients.append((self.client_host,self.client_port))
                log.msg("connection from %s:%s\n"%(self.client_host,str(self.client_port)))
                self.transport.write(
                        "Welcome %s:%s\n" %(self.client_host,str(self.client_port)))


        def connectionLost(self, reason):
            log.msg('Connection lost from %s:%s. Reason: %s\n' % (self.client_host,str(self.client_port),reason.getErrorMessage()))
            if (self.client_host,self.client_port) in self.factory.clients:
                self.factory.clients.remove((self.client_host,self.client_port))

    class MyFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):

        protocol = Server
        def __init__(self, clients_max=10):
            self.clients_max = clients_max
            self.clients = []          


    def main():
        """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""
        log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
        reactor.listenTCP(8000,MyFactory)
        reactor.run()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Manage" is an incredibly broad, non-specific verb.  What do you actually want to do?  What part of it is presenting difficulties for you?

Comment: Manage means disconnecting clients, send commands to them, listing real time sending and receiving data etc etc...

Comment: And what are you having problems with?

Comment: Any list of elements that ends with "etc etc" suggests an answer too long for stack overflow.  My suggestion would be to adjust your question to deal with just one of these issues, and once you understand how to do that one, you should be able to generalize.  perhaps just "disconnect"?

Comment: ok I want just to know how to disconnect clients, send commands to them throw a GUI such as pygame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a single Python program (process) that runs both your UI and your networking, you will first need to choose an appropriate Twisted reactor that integrates with the UI toolkit's event loop. See [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html).

Next, you might start with something simple, like have a button that when pressed will send a text message to all currently connected clients.

Another thing: what clients will connect? Browsers (also)? If so, you might contemplate about using WebSocket instead of raw TCP.